# how to compile file list through shell by python

Tags: python-3.x, file, cmd, filelist

i am new in python. i have to create a list with file name with its path and some commands in python. which i have to execute in cmd. it will open compiler and the set some settings in it for compiling the files.
my problem is, when i type manully couple of files with commands in cmd at that time it will work but when i execute same list through python it says it can not find the pinmap file. the following lines i write in cmd and it works fine. (apc and start with '-' are command of cmd) 
apc G:\Organisation\TE\Patel\ASCII_Open_Program\src\atp\Functionality\clk_Watchdog.atp G:\Organisation\TE\Patel\ASCII_Open_Program\src\atp\Functionality\CP_UV_Threshold.atp  -opcode_mode single  -pinmap_workbook G:\Organisation\TE\Patel\ASCII_Open_Program\src\xls\PinMap_BE.txt  -comments

i think i am doing same thing in python. my code is

```
def APC_Compiler():
    list = ["apc "]
    #list.append('apc ')
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(atp_folder_path + '\\SCAN'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".atp"):                  
                 list.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    list.append(' -opcode_mode single ')
    list.append(' -pinmap_workbook  ')
    list.append(' G:\\Organisation\\TE\\Patel\\ASCII_Open_Program\\src\\xls\\PinMap_BE.txt')
    list.append(' -comments ')              
    print (list)
    subprocess.call(list)
```

can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong. 
is there any better way to make the list of files with commands and executing it??

Comment: I am sorry that i did not focus on my grammar, I will keep in mind next time. but i now i got the answer. I have to execute all the list with command in to open string. which i have done using ' '.join(list) command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution, all i have to do, is to add one instruction which can convert all the list in to one single string and execute it. I have commented the near to the instruction, which i have added to solve my problem.

```
def apc_compiler():
        """ Compiles all the *.atp files into *.pat file """

    list = ['apc ']
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(atp_folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.atp'):
                list.append(os.path.join(root, file) + ' ')

    list.append(' -opcode_mode single ')
    list.append(' -pinmap_workbook ')
    list.append(pinmap_folder_path)
    list.append(' -comments ')
    list = ''.join(list) # instruction to convert list in to single string

    subprocess.call(list)
```